# Using touchesbegan, touchesmoved and touchesended is not animating the dragging smoothly

Tags: ios

I want to move an object from my viewcontroller with the methods touchesbegan, touchesmoved and touchesended. It works the way I want (if the distance it's moved isn't big enough it will be placed to it's initial position) but the animation of the dragging isn't smooth. Can anyone help me, to make it a fluent dragging movement?

This is my code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Touch Gestures


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.view == _topCard) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:_topCard];
        touchCenterOffset = CGPointMake([touch view].center.x - touchPoint.x,
                                        [touch view].center.y - touchPoint.y);
        [self animateFirstTouchAtPoint:touchPoint];
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.view == _topCard) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:_topCard];
        CGPoint pointOnTable = [_topCard convertPoint:[touch locationInView:_topCard] toView:_topCard.superview];
                CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(location.x + touchCenterOffset.x,
                                        location.y + touchCenterOffset.y);
        [touch view].center = newCenter;

        if (pointOnTable.x > 180) {
            NSLog(@"Aktionismus");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"KEIN Aktionismus");
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.view == _topCard) {
        CGPoint pointOnTable = [_topCard convertPoint:[touch locationInView:_topCard] toView:_topCard.superview];

        if (pointOnTable.x > 180) {
            NSLog(@"Aktionismus");
        } else {
            [self animatePutBackTopCard:FLIP_DURATION];
        }
    }
}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.view == _topCard) {
        [self animatePutBackTopCard:FLIP_DURATION];
    }

}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Animations

- (void)animateFirstTouchAtPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
    /*[UIView animateWithDuration:GROW_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS animations:^{
        _topCard.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_topCard.transform, 1.2, 1.2);
    }];*/
}

- (void)animatePutBackTopCard:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        CGPoint originalCenter = CGPointMake(ORIGIN_CENTER_X,ORIGIN_CENTER_Y);
        _topCard.center = originalCenter;
    }];
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the [UIGestures for iPhone](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I figured out where my problem was:

I didn't track the movement of the object in the superview, but of the touchpoint on the object.

This is the adjusted code which works fine with smooth dragging:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.view == _topCard) {
        translation = [touch locationInView:_topCard.superview];
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.view == _topCard) {
      CGPoint newTranslation = [touch locationInView:_topCard.superview];
      _topCard.frame = CGRectOffset(_topCard.frame, newTranslation.x - translation.x, newTranslation.y - translation.y);
      translation = newTranslation;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how I'm doing the moving of an object and it's working smoothly:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    float difx = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].x;

    float dify = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].y - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].y;

    CGAffineTransform newTransform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, difx, dify);

    self.transform = newTransform1;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    float difx = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].x;

    float dify = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].y - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].y;

    CGAffineTransform newTransform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, difx, dify);

    self.transform = newTransform1;

}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

I think you could adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You are right, your code works smoothly. Can you maybe tell me the reason why you have the same code in "touchesBegan" and "touchesmoved"?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to drag [a custom UIView](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/Tile.m):

[image: app screenshot]

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previous = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

    if (!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(self.transform)) {
        location = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(location, self.transform);
        previous = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(previous, self.transform);
    }

    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame,
                              (location.x - previous.x),
                              (location.y - previous.y));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to manipulate view’s frame directly, as stated in other answers. For example, it will result in very strange behavior, when using UIDynamics. 
You should set view’s center instead.

```
  override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {

        let p1 = touch.locationInView(self.superview)
        let p0 = touch.previousLocationInView(self.superview)
        let translation = CGPointMake(p1.x - p0.x, p1.y - p0.y);
        center = CGPointMake(center.x + translation.x, center.y + translation.y)//set views center
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dragging, I'd recommend using the panGestureRecognizer instead.

Information can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)